# Is there any way to get a information on activities performed by a specific box user through box api?

Tags: box-api

Say I want to know what all operation a box user "x" has performed in last week. Is there any way to acheive this via box api??
Or for that matter given a file id can we get a list of all the activities performed.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the administrator of a Box enterprise and the user is within your enterprise, you can do one of two things:

1. [Fetch all events in the enterprise](http://developers.box.com/docs/#events-get-events-in-an-enterprise) within your timespan of interest and manually filter them to the particular user using the `event.created_by.login`.  You can filter to a particular file using the `event.source.id` property.
2. [Fetch the particular user's events](http://developers.box.com/docs/#events-get-events-for-a-user) using the [On Behalf Of](http://developers.box.com/docs/#users-on-behalf-of-enterprise-user) API.

Otherwise, you can only fetch events for the user represented by the Bearer token.